# How to connect to mongodb cluster from mongodb cloud manager from local machine

Tags: c, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How would I connect to the mongo shard I created using cloud manager? Here are the steps I followed.

1. login to cloud manager.
2. created replica set using the aws servers.
3. I already had an account on Ec2, so I downloaded the security and access key and used those to connect.
4. everything else was done by cloud manger and replica set was deployed.
5. now I want to connect to the cluster but the I am not able to connect to it.
6. I tried connection using the mongo installed on my local machine and using the command given in the "connect to this instance window"

Comment: Could you give more information about why you are not able to? how are you trying to do it? what errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm wondering what c stands for? I mean in the tags.

Comment: I got the answer for the problem. I had change security setting for security group which caused the server not visible to cloud manager. later on I have to made it visible to all. Do you know what setting I have to do for security group so that these Ec2 servers are visible only to my local laptop and cloud manager.